# how to deploy artifact of VM desktop?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I tried to copy task extension on azure pipeline: `$vmFolder="c:/users/[username]/desktop` and also tried 
`$vmFolder="c:/users/public/desktop` but still my artefacts are deployed inside `c:/azagent/work/` location. If anyone has an idea, please explain me the process step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a little more detail about what you're trying to achieve?

My feeling is that there may be a confussion about what is an **Agent** (*C:\azagent\work* is the work directory in a machine where you, very likely, have installed an Agent) and the **Machine where you want to deploy your code** to run.

Bests.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish the build artifacts in Azure DevOps, for the location you could only choose "Server" or a UNC file share.

> **Artifact publish location argument:**
>
> Azure Pipelines/TFS (TFS 2018 RTM and older: Artifact type: Server)
>   is the best and simplest choice in most cases. This choice causes the
>   artifacts to be stored in Azure Pipelines or TFS. But **if you're
>   using a private Windows agent**, you've got the option to drop to a
>   UNC file share.

More details please refer our official doc -- [Artifacts in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)

The remaining alternative is to add a download artifacts task in the end of pipeline to download your published artifacts to your Destination directory.